# Email Bounce Address

Tags: plugins, email, smtp

I'm having a little issue with my SMTP. I use a plugin **WP MAIL** to manage the email configurations as it makes it easy to run in/outgoing emails without leaving unsent or stuck mails. 
Everything is working properly but the email shows this `Uxxxxxxxx@uk-m247-web127.main-hosting.eu` as Bounce address which is not good for SEO plus it shows the username of my **WP** installation, which is not the best for the security.I'd really like to change that.  Any idea to work this out?

**PS**: `/home/Uxxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-admin/options-general.php` this is also shown from the received email. Any way to change this either?

Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be the configured SMTP server by your hosting. It might be possible to configure this if you have CPANEL included. If that's the case, take a look at this [article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-use-smtp-server-to-send-wordpress-emails/). It explains how you can create your own SMTP address and use it for sending e-mails from your website.

Alternatively, you can use another provider to send emails for you. I can recommend sending your emails with a SMTP provider like Sendgrid. You will need to signup, add CNAME records to your domain, and you can use for example mailing.example.com as your sender address. It offers a ton of features and Deliverability is great. With a plugin such as Post [SMTP Mailer/Log](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-smtp/) this can be easily configured.

Let me know if it helps you!
Cheers..